# how to configure loopback 4 with firestore datasource

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, loopbackjs, node-modules

I am trying to configure loopback4 with firestore data source using loopback-connector-firestore connector. when i am trying to post it is showing error code 500 with Error: Internal Server Error. Please tell me where i am exactly doing wrong.

Comment: Can you please post some code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple.

1. First follow the steps to create datasource running the console command `lb4 datasource`.
2. When the command line ask you for the connector select `other`.
3. When the command line ask you for the connector's package name paste this `loopback-connector-firestore`. Please note that all connector for loopback 3 must work in loopback 4.
4. Then you should use a service account. Go to **Project Settings > Service Accounts** and press the **Generate new private key** button, in the Google Cloud Platform Console. Generate a new private key and *save the JSON* file.
5. Then in the `src/datasources` project folder open your new `datasourceName.datasource.json` file and add the following keys that you can find in the downloaded JSON file from the Google Cloud Platform in the previous step:

```
{
  "projectId": "",
  "clientEmail":  "",
  "privateKey": "",
  "databaseName": "Optional, Default: projectId"
}
```

That is all. Now, if you have models, repositories and controller previously created you can run `npm start`, open the explorer and test your endpoints.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try and let know the result.